# Karate API : * def from response is throwing syntax error

Tags: karate

I am setting up an E2E test and chaining my request/responses. I am defining variables from each response and using them in the next call.

Its working up to a point, and then a problem surfaces when defining off the 2nd response.

If I def operationId, operationSubject, or operationStatus *(e.g response.operationId)*, it works.
If I store anything from the results *(e.g response.results.0.personId)* it throws this error
***Expected ; but found .0
response.results.0.personId***

My response:

{
"operationId": "922459ecxxxxx",
"operationSubject": "BATCH_ENROLLMENT",
"operationStatus": "PROCESSED",
"results": {
"0": {
"personId": "367a73b5xxxx",
"status": "PRE_AUTH",
"email": "mquinter+TEST.69387488@email.com",
"loanNumber": null
},
"1": {
"personId": "56f060fd-e34xxxxxx",
"status": "PRE_AUTH",
"email": "mquintxxxx@email.com",
"loanNumber": null
}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

That's not how to access data in JSON. See this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71847841/143475

Maybe you meant to do this:

```
* def foo = response.results[0].personId
```

Comment: That is how I am defining it            (ie.
* def borrowerID = response.results.0.personId
I also tried
* def borrowerID = response.results.[0].personId

......either way get 
SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:17 Expected ident but found [
response.results.[0].personId
* def borrowerID = response.results.[0].personId

Comment: Full ERROR
..........

[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   ExamplesTest.testParallel:17 js failed:
>>>>
01: response.results.[0].personId
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:17 Expected ident but found [
response.results.[0].personId

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/143475/peter-thomas

I see the issue - It wasn't finding the response because I wasn't giving it enough time before the next call.

I put a sleep in there and its working as expected.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should look at `retry until`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823180/143475